# Filter form based on unbound control value

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form bound to a query, except for one field that I am leaving unbound. The idea is that the user will enter a value in that textbox and press a button to bring up the record. I have some code that I thought would work based on the interwebs. When I use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter(filter_string)` I get a popup asking for the value to filter on (which is not what I want). When I go ahead and paste it in, the form does not get filled. When I use `Me.Form.Filter = filter_string`, sometimes the form fills, but always with the same record, regardless of what the `filter_string` says. An example `filter_string` is

```
filter_string = "InventoryDetailsID = 'B01MFC000100/01'"
```

I have another similar form that, instead of filling with an existing query, generates the query (with 5 joins) and fills the form from the resulting recordset. It works just fine, but is slow because it has to run the query each time. That is why I want to use a method where I generate the query once, and then filter it.

**Edit**

Oh, and I also tried using a variant on the run-the-query-every-time approach, where I query the already generated query (the one I'm trying to filter). I'm using:

```
query_string = "SELECT * FROM qry_ISBN_All WHERE InventoryDetailsID LIKE '" & Me.InventoryDetailsID & "';"
```

But I get the error `Run-time error '3061' Too few parameters, expected 1`

**Edit II**

```
Private Sub btn_Seek_Click()
    Dim temp As String
    filter_string = "InventoryDetailsID = '" & Me.InventoryDetailsID & "'"
    Me.temp = filter_string
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.Form.Filter = filter_string
    Me.FilterOn = True
    'DoCmd.ApplyFilter (filter_string)
'    Dim query_string As String
'    query_string = "SELECT * FROM qry_ISBN_All WHERE InventoryDetailsID LIKE '" & Me.InventoryDetailsID & "';"

End Sub
```

Typical filter string is given. It is printed to the form control `Me.temp`.

Answer (score 1):

After this line:

```vb
Me.Filter = filter_string
```

Add this in:

```vb
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Also I agree, run the query every time approach is definitely overkill.  The filter should provide you with the functionality you seek.  You just simply have to "turn it on" after you set it.

Comment: Hmmm. It's still bringing up the popup, and still not finding the records.

Comment: Can you post your full code and also a `Debug.Print` of your filter string?